# join list elements by two

Tags: python-3.x, join

I have this list

`mylist = [10.0, 10.3333, 10.6666, 11.0]`

and I want to create labels like:

`labels = ['10.0-10.3333', '10.3333-10.6666', '10.6666-11.0']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [40]: mylist = [10.0, 10.3333, 10.6666, 11.0]

In [41]: [f"{mylist[i]}-{mylist[i+1]}" for i in range(len(mylist)-1)]
Out[41]: ['10.0-10.3333', '10.3333-10.6666', '10.6666-11.0']
```